# How to extact the list of values in the data attribute using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table like this.

```
<table id="data-grid">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td data-field="name">Name</td>
        <td data-field="address1">Address Line 1</td>
        <td data-field="city">City</td>
        <td data-field="state">State</td>
        <td data-field="postalcode">Postal Code</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I want to pull all values in the "data-field". 
I have used `document.getElementById("data-grid").querySelectorAll("td")`, which gives an object

```
{
0: <td data-field="name">​
1: <td data-field="address1">​
2: <td data-field="city">​
3: <td data-field="state">​
4: <td data-field="postalcode">​
........
}
```

How to get a list of what is in the data-field like `["name", "address1", "city", "state", "postalcode"]`? It can be an object or an array. Either one will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to an array with `Array.from` then call `.map` on it:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#data-grid td")).map(v => v.dataset.field)
```

(also I changed the selector to `#data-grid td` to get rid of the `getElementById`)

Comment: Cannot THANK YOU enough for the solution. I appreciate.